# Retrieve user with Cognito Hosted UI in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Using AWS Amplify, I [configured](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#setup-your-cognito-app-client) the Amazon Cognito Hosted UI in my Angular project to try the Google sign in.

From now, I can call the hosted UI and have the redirected url like this one: http://localhost:4200/authenticated?code=f4c34ad6

With the received code, I'd like to retrieve the current user.

According to this [post](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1395), I can do it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authenticated',
  templateUrl: './authenticated.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authenticated.component.css']
})
export class AuthenticatedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public router: Router
  ) {
    console.log('constructor');
    Hub.listen('auth', this, 'AuthCodeListener');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onHubCapsule(capsule: any) {
    const { channel, payload } = capsule; // source
    if (channel === 'auth' && payload.event === 'signIn') {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((data) => {
        console.log('---', data) // THIS WORKS for Hosted UI!
        // redirect to other page
      });
    }
  }

}
```

But without success. The `onHubCapsule` does not display on the console.

Here is my code to call the hosted UI :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <button class="button" (click)="login()">Log in with 
Google</button>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent {
  private url = 'https://' + 'auth-social.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com' + '/login?redirect_uri=' + 'http://localhost:4200/authenticated' + '&response_type=' + 'code' + '&client_id=' + '7b9pefeu654i7u342******';

  login() {
    window.location.assign(this.url);
  }

}
```

What is missing to retrieve the user?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit - 07/12/2018**

In my main.ts, I have the following configuration :

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import amplify from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // Domain name
    domain: 'auth-social.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com',

    // Authorized scopes
    scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],

    // Callback URL
    redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:4200/authenticated',

    // Sign out URL
    redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200',

    // 'code' for Authorization code grant, 
    // 'token' for Implicit grant
    responseType: 'code',

    // optional, for Cognito hosted ui specified options
    options: {
      // Indicates if the data collection is enabled to support Cognito advanced security features. By default, this flag is set to true.
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true
    }
  },
  amplify
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this oauth configuration and it will work:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#configuring-the-hosted-ui

So the configuration should look like this:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import amplify from './aws-exports';

const oauth = {
    // Domain name
    domain : 'your-domain-prefix.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com', 

    // Authorized scopes
    scope : ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid','aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'], 

    // Callback URL
    redirectSignIn : 'http://www.example.com/signin', 

    // Sign out URL
    redirectSignOut : 'http://www.example.com/signout',

    // 'code' for Authorization code grant, 
    // 'token' for Implicit grant
    responseType: 'code',

    // optional, for Cognito hosted ui specified options
    options: {
        // Indicates if the data collection is enabled to support Cognito advanced security features. By default, this flag is set to true.
        AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag : true
    }
}

Amplify.configure({
  ...amplify,
  Auth: {
    oauth: oauth
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried to add the configuration in the `main.ts` (see edit) but It still not working. Is it something else to do?

Comment: In Amplify.configure object change property: "amplify" to "...amplify" - it needs to be what's inside the amplify object, not the object itself.

Comment: Not sure to understand. amplify here refer to `import amplify from './aws-exports';`. Maybe can you update your answer?